# move a div left/right viewportwidth on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

What I'm trying to do is make a simple html/css horizontal slider that spawns the entire viewport.

I've already got a piece of javascript that calculates the users viewport and gives certain div's the desired width/height, but I can't seem to get the buttons to animate left and right the desired amount of px. (Wich get's calculated through the getviewport.js)

I know I'm close, I just can't figure out how to get the variable viewportwidth to my buttons.

This is the getviewport.js

```
function resize() {


        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
            viewportheight = window.innerHeight
        }

        // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

        else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' & typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
            viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
        }

        // older versions of IE

        else {
            viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
            viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
        }
        document.getElementById("portfolio").style.height = viewportheight+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio1").style.height = viewportheight+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio2").style.height = viewportheight+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio3").style.height = viewportheight+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio1").style.width = viewportwidth+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio2").style.width = viewportwidth+"px";
        document.getElementById("portfolio3").style.width = viewportwidth+"px";
}
```

This is the animation and button script:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function slider_animate(px) {
      $('#moving_part').animate({
        'marginLeft' : px
      });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="slider_animate('-=viewportwidth')" />
<input type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="slider_animate('+=viewportwidth')" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct you just want to send viewport's width to `slider_animate()` function. If that is what you want you can simply do.

```
<input type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="slider_animate('-=' + $(window).width() + 'px')" />
<input type="button" value="Move Right" onclick="slider_animate('+=' + $(window).width() + 'px')" />
```